# Configure continuum 1.2.3 with maven2 project; "Username isn't defined."

Tags: apache, maven-2, cvs, version-control, continuum

I use continuum 1.2.3 to build maven projects. On a fresh continuum installation, I added a pom by upload. 
I try to build, and get the following error:

```
Exception:
Exception while executing SCM command.
```

My SCM URL looks like this: (replaced domain name)

```
scm:cvs:pserver:cvs.example.com:/Projects:car/wheel/
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the SCM provider couldn't find your credentials so failed. If you run the build with `-X` switch it should give more details of the failure reason.

Update: from the [format for CVS SCM URLs](http://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html), the expected format for pserver is:

```
scm:cvs<delimiter>pserver<delimiter>[username[<delimiter>password]@]servername[<delimiter>port]<delimiter>path_to_repository<delimiter>module_name
```

If you have a `:` in the path, you should use `|` as a separator, perhaps on Continuum there is some other processing interfering and using `|` will resolve it, e.g.

```
scm:cvs|pserver|[user]|[password]@cvs.example.com|/Projects|car/wheel/
```

Assuming that is the cause, you don't want to include your SCM credentials in published files. You can configure Maven to use settings for many of the providers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255593/externalising-scm-credentials-with-maven/1255615#1255615) for more details.

Comment: Providing username and password in scm url, i get the following error: //start of output

Provider message: The cvs command failed.
Command output: 

//end of output

In the continuum.log is the following line: 
     2009-10-07 14:04:10,955 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.continuum.scm.manager.Slf4jScmLogger  - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:floppy@cvs.example.com:/Projects -q checkout -d 3 car/wheel/"

running this on command line (windows) sucessfully checks out the sources. But it doesn't work using continuum. Maybe i must use the native cvs implementation?