# Jenkins: Use credentials from Credentials Plugin in the M2 Release Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

I want to use the [M2 Relase Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) to release artifacts on a Jenkins server. The access to and checkout of the sources from Subversion is done with help of the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin). For tagging and committing the changes during the *maven release:prepare* phase I need (in my case) the same credentials.

Is there a way to convince the M2 Release Plugin to take credentials from the Credentials Plugin?

Note: I don’t want to insert the credentials manually in the SCM login/password fields and I don’t want to store the credentials in an extra settings.xml file on the server as often suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented the following solution, where I do not have to insert the credentials manually again, but where the credentials are stored in a temporary settings.xml file on the file system during the build.

With help of the [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) I have created an empty settings.xml and used the stored credentials as server settings. The server id I have filled with the hostname from the scm url (see answer to [Externalising SCM credentials with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791460)). In the *Build Environment* section of the Jenkins job configuration I have enabled *Provide Configuration Files*, selected the self created settings.xml, assigned a *Variable* and used this variable in *Release goals and options* with `-s $variable` (like in [Running the Maven Release Plugin with Jenkins](https://dzone.com/articles/running-maven-release-plugin)).